# What does the -lt mean in the boolean expression for this bash while loop?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm guessing it stands for less than based on the output, but where can I find documentation about this syntax?

```
     #!/bin/bash 
     COUNTER=0
     while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
         echo The counter is $COUNTER
         let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
     done
```

Comment: `for counter in {0..9};do echo "The counter is $counter";done` is IMHO safer and clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-lt` is less than (strictly).

The man page you're looking for is [`man test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html).

> ```
> n1 -lt  n2
> ```
>
> True if the integer n1 is algebraically less than the integer n2; otherwise, false.
>
> ```
> n1 -le  n2
> ```
>
> True if the integer n1 is algebraically less than or equal to the integer n2; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is a loop iteration

```
 COUNTER=0                         // set zero to variable COUNTER
 while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ];       // check while $COUNTER less than 10 (-lt)
 do                                // * if the check is true, do this
     echo The counter is $COUNTER  // print the string
     let COUNTER=COUNTER+1         // reassign COUNTER = current value - 1
 done                              // end of *
```

The docs :- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Answer (score 0):

Check out this.

http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/test.1.php